# Which Cloud Computing provider support user-provided Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, cloud-computing, openvz

I'm looking for a Cloud Computing provider which provide servers on-demand and billed per hour (like EC2) with the ability to use an alternate kernel (they often use Xen for cloud servers). I want OpenVZ and it's never available.

Amazon EC2 and Rackspace Cloud Server don't support that.

Are there other Cloud Computing providers which support that?

Note: Providers which are not Xen-based (VMWare, KVM, ...) can also be an option as it is simpler to change the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet might be looking at providers which use Eucalyptus or similar technologie. From looking at http://www.eucalyptus.com/about/partners/ , i found this :

http://www.elastichosts.com/

Hope that helps you get started :)

Comment: I've been looking at ElasticHosts the past week and am very impressed. @OP: They offer a five-day free trial, give 'em a spin. You'll want to do some real-world-like tests of performance if your app is disk-bound, since EH's "disks" are all slices of RAID1 arrays to which you may (in some situations) be connected via iSCSI. The one place I'm not yet convinced is disk throughput, but I need to run more tests.  The staff are knowledgeable, accessible, and friendly.